# Missing composer.json file while installing composer for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am new to Laravel. I am trying to install Composer for Laravel but getting this error:

> Composer could not find a composer.json file in C:\xampp\htdocs
>
> To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

Comment: What do you mean 'Composer for laravel'? Did you follow steps from doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.5#installing-laravel?

Comment: first you should download composer for windows https://getcomposer.org/

Answer (score 5):

To create a missing `composer.json` file, you need to run:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

See: [Installing Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5#installing-laravel).